# Tomcat + Spring + JSON подойдут для сайта с рейтингом? (вопрос от новичков-студентов)

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, tomcat

Есть задание: сделать сайт с рейтингом развлекательных заведений города и со встроенной картой (на которой собственно эти заведения с рейтингом и будут показаны). В наличии команда из Java-разработчиков (естественно, начинающих) и таких же разработчиков на JavaScript.

Решили поставить Tomcat, на нем Spring + JSON в качестве фронтенда. Подскажите, на каких фреймворках лучше всего реализовать подобный проект, если мы не на правильном пути?

Comment: Развлекательный сайт на Java, думаю не самая лучшая идея, тем более Spring еще туда. Зачем вы себе жизнь усложняете? По какой причине , не хотите посмотреть в сторону PHP? На Java круто будет web application строить.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Возможно, мы ошиблись в том, как это все называется да и размах планов не описан. Но в целом выбрали те технологии, с которыми знакомы. РНР попросту не знаем. Интересует именно Java и JavaScript, но вот фреймворки - пока загадка.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на *StackOverflow на русском*.  Вы на правильном пути. Можете посмотреть до кучи на Spring Boot, а если хотите на фронтенде Angular.js, то сразу и JHipster. К сожалению, вопросы такого плана ("Посоветуйте библиотеку/фреймворк") [не приветствуются](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день!

Ключевой момент в нашем случае именно наличие команды java-разработчиков. Как раз учить php,python или ruby в данном случае будет усложнением.

Для еще большего упрощения жизни настоятельно советую использовать [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). В этом случае вы сразу получите исполняемый jar с Tomcat или Jetty на борту.

Работает быстро. К высоким нагрузкам при правильной архитектуре приручено.